# Выбор элемента на фрейме tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу простенький GUI со стандартными элементами Tkinter (python). На главном экране приложения есть несколько **одинаковых** контейнеров frame с **такими же** элементами типа button, entry, label.

Что бы придерживаться золотого правила DRY, элементы во фреймах (и сами фреймы) создаю циклом так:

```
for frames in range(3):
    tab = Frame(mainWindow)

    for elements in range(1, 5):

        alarmH = Entry(tab, width=2)
        alarmH.grid(column=0, row=elements)

        sounds = Combobox(tab, values=soundList)
        sounds.set("Select")
        sounds.grid(column=4, row=elements)

и т.д.
```

Так вот теперь вопрос - как обратиться к отдельному элементу одного из фреймов (допустим, что бы поменять текст или фон элемента). И вообще возможно ли?

Подозреваю, что нужно всё выносить в отдельные переменные вручную, но всё же...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сохранить ссылки на элементы в списках или словарях.

Например так:

```
frames = {}

for i in range(3):

    frames[i] = {}
    tab = Frame(mainWindow)
    frames[i]['tab'] = tab
    frames[i]['elements'] = {}
    for j in range(1, 5):
        frames[i]['elements'][j] = {}
        alarmH = Entry(tab, width=2)
        alarmH.grid(column=0, row=elements)
        frames[i]['elements'][j]['entry'] = alarmH
        sounds = Combobox(tab, values=soundList)
        sounds.set("Select")
        sounds.grid(column=4, row=elements)
        frames[i]['elements'][j]['combobox'] = sounds
```

А потом сможете через словарь обращаться к конкретному элементу:

К конкретному табу:

```
print(frames[0]['tab'])
```

Или к конкретному элементу:

```
frames[1]['elements'][0]['combobox'].set("Select")
```

Comment: Потрясающее решение! Показалось сначала, что ключи _tab_ будут одинаковыми и замещать друг друга, но потом понял что они лежат в отдельных словарях :) Не много не хватает опыта работы со вложенными словарями во вложенных словарях... **Спасибо!**

Comment: Не самое элегантное решение. Проще было бы конечно классы завести. В этот класс поместить все управляющие элементы, а его уже использовать столько раз сколько нужно.